# Where to find/edit HTML body content within node with no body UI field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need access to the body HTML content within a drupal node of a content type with no body access in the UI fields.  I need to make a change to this specific node, not the template.

Where can I access the body content?

Comment: make a SQL request

Answer (score 0):

If this is Drupal 7 then you essentially need to look in the 'field_data_body' table of the database, 'body_value' field. You might also want to check the 'body_format' to establish that it is indeed "full_html".

What is preventing access to the body field through the UI - that's not normal behaviour, perhaps there is a hook_form_alter at play in another custom module or the field_permissions module has been enabled and that field restricted to certain roles. Are you prevented from accessing the field even when logged in as user 1?

Comment: This is for the addition of a <script> tag to the body of the node.  I can add the field, but it will not work due to script tags being removed.  Also it is for one specific node, not all nodes of a type.

Comment: Your script tags are being stripped because of the format of the field (full_html, filtered_html, etc). That being said, allowing <script> tags in your user entered html is not a good idea. If you just want to add this js to a single node, use hook_node_load to get the node and check the nid then drupal_add_js() to add the javascript when you are loading the node in question.